# SenchaTouch ListView within a viewport?

Tags: java, listview, sencha-touch, viewport

I have been trying to figure out for the past few hours how to get this working and I am struggling.

I'm currently trying to make an application which has four tab buttons, each one having it's own viewport js file, this works fine, however on one of the views I need to show a list view.

This is what I have so far,

```
MobileApp.views.Settings_screen = Ext.extend(Ext.List, {

    title: "Settings    ",
    iconCls: "settings", 
    layout: 'fit',


    initComponent: function() { 

        MobileApp.listPanel = new Ext.List({
            id: 'indexlist',
            store: MobileApp.listStore,
            itemTpl: 'div class="contact">{firstName} {lastName}</div>'
        });
    },

    items: [MobileApp.listPanel], 
});

Ext.reg('settings_screen', MobileApp.views.Settings_screen);
```

However when I run the application and click on the settings tab bar button nothing appears on the screen.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks Aaron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only comment on the code you've posted so I can't tell you if there is something wrong with your tab bar-- this `Settings_screen` however has some problems...

If you're going to include your own `initComponent` function you need to call the `initComponent` function of its superclass from within your `initComponent` function... like this in your case..

```
initComponent: function() {
  MobileApp.views.Settings_screen.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
}
```

The other problem is you're creating `MobileApp.listPanel` inside the `initComponent` function so you can't include it in the `items` array like you're trying... instead get rid of the items property all together and use `this.add(MobileApp.listPanel)` from within the `initComponent` function after you've created it.

You also need to change Settings_screen to extend Ext.Panel, you don't add a List component to a List component, you need to have a container.. Whether it be another panel or the body of your viewport container..

Whether these changes are enough to get it working will depend on whether there are problems with code you didn't post.

Comment: Thanks I made the tweaks as you suggested and it seems to be working well now.